# Soft assertions in base class for multiple tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, assertj

I am new to testing and I have to use `assertj` framework for `softassertions`. These are standard assertions that are repeated over multiple tests. For every test I define new `SoftAssertion`, do the asserts and then do `.assertAll()`

This seems like a lot of boiler plate code. Is it possible to abstract the assert functions and the `assertall()` method in a base class so that my tests could extend the class?

Comment: It depends on what you are testing.
- If you are testing one feature, but with different input/output, then maybe you want to look at parametised testing (something like JUnitParams)
- If you are testing multiple classes with common behaviour (usually extend the same class), you can create a base test class for those tests to extend from.
Do you have any example code?

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. I am currently using simple Softassertions to assert strings and values. These tests by themselves are not very complex. However I have a lot of tests and in every file I define a new soft assert, perform the assertion and then call the assertall method. I was wondering if this part of the tests the can be abstracted in a base class in the before and after methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JUnitSoftAssertions` as shown here :
http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#soft-assertions

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old. But I came here searching for an answer and I formulated the answer myself. Hope this answer helps someone else. SoftAssertion can be abstracted to the BaseClass in the following way using ThreadLocal variable,

```
public class BaseTest {

    ThreadLocal<SoftAssert> softAssert = new ThreadLocal<SoftAssert>();

    @BeforeMethod
    public void initialise() {
        softAssert.set(new SoftAssert());
    }
}

public class AppTest extends BaseTest{
    @Test(alwaysRun = true)
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        softAssert.get().fail("test1() I got failed - Test1");
        softAssert.get().fail("test1() I got failed - Test1");
        softAssert.get().assertAll();
    }
    
    @Test(alwaysRun = true)
    public void test2() {
        softAssert.get().fail("test2 I got failed - Test2");
        softAssert.get().fail("test2 I got failed - Test2");
        softAssert.get().assertAll();
    }
}
```

**

```
Output:
Test1 output:
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
    test1() I got failed - Test1,
    test1() I got failed - Test1
Test2 Output:
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
    test2 I got failed - Test2,
    test2 I got failed - Test2
```

**

Comment: Note: we cannot  add assertAll in AfterMethod because, that will make testng to ignore other tests.